# Iterate two lists to find a match and return boolean using java8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have two lists as below

```
List<String> pathNames = Lists.newArrayList("/state", "/country", "/country/name");
List<String> newPaths = Lists.newArrayList("/country/name");
```

I have normal for each java code to iterate two lists to find a match and return boolean as below

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pathNames)) {
    for (String path : newPaths) {
        for (String reqPath: pathNames) {
            if(FilenameUtils.wildcardMatch(path, reqPath)) {
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to refactor and do the same in Java8, any help can be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a stream pipeline on both lists and call `anyMatch`:

```
return CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pathNames) &&
       newPaths.stream().anyMatch(np -> 
          pathNames.stream().anyMatch(pn -> FilenameUtils.wildcardMatch(np, pn)));
```

Comment: The `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pathNames) &&` is obsolete…

Comment: @Holger wouldn't have done that in fact, `!pathNames.isEmpty()` would have been enough, I think. Wanted to preserve original code.

Comment: Well, even a `!pathNames.isEmpty()` check would be unnecessary, as the stream operation does the right thing and if you suspect that there’s a high likelihood for `pathNames` to be empty while `newPaths` is large, you can optimize it by swapping the nesting, `pathNames.stream().anyMatch(pn -> newPaths.stream().anyMatch(np -> …))`. I guess, `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(…)` is one of those utility methods which adds a questionable `null` handling, so if this is really intended, an explicit `null` check should be used to document that such a `null` behavior truly is intended.